# Unable to install "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0"

Tags: .net

I'm using VS 2019 and I'm unable to install "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0".

I get the following error message :

> you cannot install the package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" .you
>   are trying to install this package in a project with
>   ".NetFramework,Version = 4.6.1"... Framework : .net Framework  = 4.6.1

My application is targetting .NET framework 4.6.1, as indicated in the above message.

Comment: Which .NET framework your application is targetting ?
What does "unable to install" mean exactly ?

Comment: This is my error : you cannot install the package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" .you are trying to install this package in a project with ".NetFramework,Version = 4.6.1"...

Comment: I have .NET 4.7.2 and nugget suggests updating Microsoft.EntitiyFrameworkCore to version 3.0.0. but by doing so I also get the same error. Looking at .NET Standard seems to me, this support will be enabled with .NET 4.8 version. So I think this is an issue with nugget, suggesting to update something that is not compatible.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/) `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0` requires `.NET Standard 2.1`. It seems like you're targeting `.NET 4.6.1` which does not implement `.NET Standard 2.1`.

Microsoft has [said](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-standard-2-1/) that they don't plan on implementing`.NET Standard 2.1` for any future full framework versions which means that you won't be able to use that particular version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

Your only option is to target `.NET Core 3.0` or choose an older version of the package that targets `.NET Standard 2.0` which is [2.2.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/2.2.6).

[image: .NET implementation support]